# Database class - Table exists?

Tags: php, sql, database, class

I am using the following awesome, easy & lightweight database class: https://codeshack.io/super-fast-php-mysql-database-class/
My problem is I do not know how I can figure out if a table in the database exists or not. I have the following PHP Code:

```
function addSts($database, $brow, $vers, $pag, $lang) {
  $tablename = "sts" . $pag;
  $stsinsert = $database->query('INSERT INTO ' . $tablename . '(id, browser, version, language, date) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, current_timestamp())', $brow, $vers, $lang);
  if ($stsinsert->affectedRows()) {
    echo "TABLE EXISTS";
    $database->close();
  }
  else {
    echo "TABLE DOES NOT EXISTS -> CREATE TABLE";
    $pagecreation = $database->query('CREATE TABLE ' . $tablename . ' (`id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `browser` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `version` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  `language` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(), PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');
    if ($pagecreation) {
      addSts($brow, $vers, $pag, $lang);
    }
  }
}
```

It always throws the following error: `Unable to prepare MySQL statement (check your syntax) - Table 'testdb.ststest' doesn't exist`
So and here we have the salad. It throws the error and does not go further to the if-else part. SO every time the table does not exist the program stops working.

Hope somebody can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` table to tell if a table exists.

Comment: Use `try/catch` to catch the error.

Comment: Since you're already using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in your second command, just run that command first and then run the insert command second.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I implemented this `$tablecheck = $database->query('SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "' . $tablename . '"');` But how can I check now what is the result? Does it return a boolean and what variable I have to read?

Comment: @AaronDietz Hubs. Sorry, that was there for testing. Unfortunately I can not use IF statements.

Comment: It returns a row of information about the table. You can just check if it returns a row or not.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement, not substitute the tablename into the SQL, to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, use the information_schema DB and query TABLES tables

```
select * from tables where TABLE_SCHEMA like '<database name>'
e.g. select * from tables where TABLE_SCHEMA like 'mydbdev'
```

the simply iterate through the results *OR*

```
select * from tables where TABLE_SCHEMA like '<database name>' AND TABLE_NAME like '<table name>';
```

and count the rows (should be 0 if not present or 1 if it is).

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar mentioned in the comments, you can use `try/catch` statements to do this.

```
function addSts($database, $brow, $vers, $pag, $lang) {

    $tablename = "sts" . $pag;

    try {
        // try to insert first
        $stsinsert = $database->query('INSERT INTO ' . $tablename . '(id, browser, version, language, date) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, current_timestamp())', $brow, $vers, $lang);

        if ($stsinsert->affectedRows()) {
            echo "TABLE EXISTS";
            $database->close();
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e){
        echo "TABLE DOES NOT EXISTS -> CREATE TABLE";

        $pagecreation = $database->query('CREATE TABLE ' . $tablename . ' (`id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `browser` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `version` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  `language` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE(), PRIMARY KEY (`id`))');

        if ($pagecreation) {
            // call the function to insert data
            addSts($brow, $vers, $pag, $lang);
        }
    }
}
```